# Showing function is well defined (measure theory)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Firstly apologies for the related sub questions in one post, but it felt better to give the complete question in one post rather then three separate posts repeating all the notation.

Given a measure space $(X,A,\mu)$ and a non-negative sequence of functions $f_{i}:(X,A)\rightarrow (\overline{\mathbb{R}}, B(\overline{\mathbb{R}}))$ such that $f_{i} \geq f_{i+1}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}, x \in X$, where $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ denotes the extended reals and $B(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ denotes the Borel sets.

(1): Let $f(x) = \lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}(x)$ for all $x \in X$.Prove that $f$ is a well-defined function and $\int_{X}f_{1} d\mu < \infty \Rightarrow \lim_{i \to \infty} \int_{X}f_{i} d\mu = \int_{X}f d\mu$.

(2): Are there a sequence of functions with these criteria and $\int_{X}f_{i}d \mu = \infty$ for all $ i \in \mathbb{N}$ but $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}f_{i} d\mu \neq \int_{X}f d\mu$

Attempt:

(1): I am sure what I need to do to show $f$ is well-defined. Do I need to take $x$ and $y$ and show $f_{i}(x) = f_{i}(y)$?

Since $f_{i}$ is non-negative and monotonic by hypothesis, the Monotone Convergence Theorem is permissible. Therefore $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}f_{i}d \mu = \int_{X} \lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}d \mu = \int_{X} f d\mu$. Note that $\int_{X}f_{1}d\mu < \infty$ therefore each subsequent integral is also (by monotonicity).

(2): I think the answer is that there does exist such sequences but I am struggling to think of a counter example. I initially thought of $f_{i} = i \chi_{(0, \frac{1}{i}]}$ but I don't think that works as each integral is not then infinite.

EDITED into 2 questions

Comment: You need to show that $f$ actually exists, namely, that the limit exists. For the last point, consider $\chi_{[i,\infty)}$.

Comment: No, you cannot apply Monotone Convergence here. MCT assumes that $f_{n+1}\ge f_n$, not the other way around.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for spotting that! Do I perhaps need to use another result? I am thinking perhaps I could use Fatou's lemma somehow, or the fact $f_{i} \geq f_{i+1}$ means the sequence is bounded above, and since it is non-negative it is bounded below by $0?$ (not sure if this is true), I am a little bit stuck.

Comment: The facts that $0\le f_n\le f_1$ and $\int f_1<\infty$ give exactly the major hypothesis of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Probably it's asking to show that limit exists, but I am not sure, as it should be considered trivial at this point

(2) If you already have Monotone Convergence Theorem then it's fine, but as the statement is almost exactly the theorem itself, may be you are asked for proof that doesn't use it?

(3) Consider $f_i(x) = \mathbb I_{(0, 1/i)}(x)/{x}$ on $[0, 1]$. What is pointwise limit of $f_i$? What is integral of each of them and of this limit?

Comment: Thanks. Your example in (3): The pointwise limit is $0$ for each $f_{i}$ the integral is $\int_{X}f_{i}d\mu = \frac{1}{i}/x =  \frac{x}{i}$? so the limit is then also $0$??

Comment: You get $$ \int_X f_i d\mu = \int_0^{1/i} \frac{1}{x} dx = \infty. $$